# how can I check if a specific mealy machine can generate a specific output?

Tags: string, matching, fsm

if I have a mealy machine, and I have a large string, how can I check if the mealy machine can generate that string?

I thought about converting the mealy machine to a regexp, but I am not clear on how to do that either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would start at the end. Reverse all directions (yes, that means that a gate may now receive one value and output two), and use the string as input, in reverse order. whenever you reach some gate or black box element, you have it's output; figure out all possible inputs that would lead to that output, and continue going backwards non-deterministically.
If at the end of the string you reach some input (or a group of inputs), then that (or those) input is an input that produces the given string. Otherwise, the string isn't generate-able by that machine.

A different approach (sometimes simpler, sometimes not), would be to try and see what are all the strings that the machine generates, or try and find some attribute that all those strings must satisfy, and that the given string does not (e.g. if you don't know exactly what strings aer generated by the machine, but you know they all start with "A", and the given string doesn't).